# Attachment Folder emptied, and cant open emulator

Tags: android-emulator, filenotfoundexception

My emulator isnt opening, and showing errors in output
2 days ago i deleted some folders related to emulator but they auto generated again
Then i tried to restore and try again with the original folders, but still didnt work

I pressed Ctrl + F5 to open emulator as always, but then in OUTPUT it shows error

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98FvP.png)